# What is the expected behaviour of "never accept third party cookies" in firefox?

Tags: firefox, cookies

I use Firefox 24.0 on Lubuntu 12.04. I have set "accept third party cookies - never" in preferences. But when I open Lightbeam, I see many third party cookies. So could someone explain what more I need to do to block them?

Comment: What is Lightbeam?

Comment: Lightbeam is an addon recently released by Mozilla https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/lightbeam/

Comment: Okay, I knew it as Collusion.

Comment: I use [selectivecookiedelete](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/selectivecookiedelete/) to manage cookies on my system.